# Figure positioning in Sweave

Tags: floats, sweave

I starting learning Sweave today, and I am having difficulty positioning my figures correctly. I am finding that when I use the figure environment, the position of the figure doesn't correspond to its position in the document. Here is a minimal example of a .Rnw file showing with this problem:

```
%figure appears after both text A and text B
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
Text A
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
hist(rnorm(100))
@
\end{center}
\caption{histogram}
\label{fig:hist}
\end{figure}

Text B
\end{document}
```

In this example, text A and text B both appear after the figure, which is not what I would expect. Surprisingly, if I don't use the figure environment, the figure is positioned correctly:

```
%figure appears between text A and text B 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
Text A
\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
hist(rnorm(100))
@
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why surprisingly? This is not a problem; it's the expected behaviour for floating objects (`figure` is one of such objects). Please refer to this excellent answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/3954 by Frank Mittelbach.

Comment: have a look at Q2 and 3 of the [faq](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent)

Comment: An alternative to options `[!h]` or `[H]` is do not use the figure environment at all. You still can use numbered captions using a KOMA Script class or the packages `caption` or `capt-of` that offer the `\captionof` command for captions outside floats (although I always prefer a well `\ref`erenced `[tbp]` float).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I didn't actually include an option for the figure position, such as [!h], this is of course the easiest solution.